# An algorithm to place N bishops on NxN board

Tags: algorithm

The problem: place N bishops on NxN board in a way, where all squares would be occupied or attacked with at least one of them.

What would be an efficient algorithm for solving this problem?

Comment: I'm sure somebody can help you out; where, exactly, are you stuck?

Comment: Why not use backtracking? :-P

Comment: Well... There is a similar problem with queens, but all you have to do with them is check if the queen currently being placed is placed on a legal square. But with bishops, do you have to be aware of empty squares throughout the whole algorithm? It's very inefficient, isn't it? As you need to "redraw" the board after placing/removing every bishop.

Comment: I think the problem you are referring to (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) states that the queens are not allowed to attack each other. The bishop problem as you have stated it doesn't have this constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why backtrack? Use the small number of solutions to obtain a proof.

Even a greedy algorithm will suffice: Count the number of squares reachable from each square. Pick a square with the greatest reach that doesn't overlap with a previously picked reach. Repeat.

Ambiguity generates horizontal, vertical, and side-of-center variations.

N bishops is only enough to reach each square with exactly one bishop. If you picked squares with overlapping reach, the final tally of reachable squares would be lower. Hmm, maybe you need to quantify how much lower for any given bad square. Sounds doable.

For such a huge problem space, brute-force backtracking doesn't sound promising.

Answer (score 7):

```
_ _ _ _ ♗ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ ♗ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ ♗ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ ♗ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ ♗ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ ♗ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ ♗ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ ♗ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ ♗ _ _ _ _
```

Comment: The word "backtracking" suggests that the OP wants _all_ the possible bishop arrangements.

Comment: I know the solution. I need help with the algorithm.

Comment: @Cinnamon: The algorithm - 1) Choose any row or column. 2) Place bishops in every cell in this row or column. Seriously though, if this isn't what you want it would help if you added a little more detail to your question. Explain: what you want, how and why backtracking should be used, what you've tried, your code if any, and what problems you are having getting it working.

Comment: @Mark: They have to be in the center.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Good point. I need one more step: 3) If your chosen row or column doesn't work, backtrack and try a new row/column. So now the algorithm also includes backtracking as requested. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There is a minimum and a maximum solution for this problem it isn't as trivial.

Check this [BishopsProblem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BishopsProblem.html) or more [detailed](http://books.google.de/books?id=aVLLYiu8hs0C&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=n+bishops+problem&source=bl&ots=30zalgydSA&sig=YOeoKlIdT3Ea4HwgF0O27DIwaVE&hl=de&ei=AebBS73fJoTzOfTN7ZYE&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CEYQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=n%20bishops%20problem&f=false)

I'm sure you will easily find an example in c.

Comment: I couldn't find a single example in C. Only theory.

Comment: @Cinnamon this (2nd listing) could be adopted http://compsci.ca/v3/viewtopic.php?t=21497 for bishops moves

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're asking for some optimizations, since the backtracking algorithm is what it is.

First thing to notice is that you can separate the black and white - you take the sum of `B_i * W_j` where `i + j = N`.  You can also visualize the diagonals as a simple grid (with constraints) as it'll likely make the code tighter and maybe easier to understand.  Another optimization is noticing that the color does not necessarily matter -- the results for some blacks can be used for some whites.  Figure out when this happen and when it doesn't.

Hope this is a good enough boost -- should be sufficient for some smallish N's.